# openai_ros q-learning example not work

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, As I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/openai_ros/TurtleBot2%20with%20openai_ros) from [OpenAI_ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/openai_ros) to play around Q learning on a Gazebo simulated turtlebot in a maze. However, I cannot initiate my turtlebot. I have succesfully downloaded and built [openai_ros](https://bitbucket.org/theconstructcore/openai_ros.git) and [openai_example_projects](https://bitbucket.org/theconstructcore/openai_examples_projects/src/master/) in my ROS workspace. I'm using `Ubuntu 16.04`+`ROS-Kinetic` + `Gazebo-7.0`.

Basically, I'm following these steps:

1. `$ roslaunch gym_construct main.launch` to start gazebo simulation (this part looks fine to me).
2. `$ roslaunch turtle2_openai_ros_example start_training.launch` and this will give me following error messages.

   [ERROR] [1534517590.397706, 29.824000]: WORLD RESET
   [ERROR] [1534517590.399843, 29.826000]: NOT Initialising Simulation Physics Parameters
   [WARN] [1534517590.401831, 29.828000]: Start Init ControllersConnection
   [WARN] [1534517590.401994, 29.828000]: END Init ControllersConnection

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300870/openai_ros-q-learning-example-not-work/) by [FloppyHank](https://answers.ros.org/users/31941/floppyhank/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-08-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm one of the developers of the package.
your steps are correct.

I think that you have no error when executing the code and that everything is working. The thing is that, due to going fast in the deployment of the code, we have used ERROR and WARN messages to show different colors of messages for our own debugging purpose. Then we forgot to put it back to normal info messages.

What I mean is that those messages are not error messages, just INFO messages. We are going to change this next week.

So you should have a list of messages like this:

```
* /turtlebot2/wait_time: 0.1
 
NODES
/
turtlebot2_maze (turtle2_openai_ros_example/start_qlearning.py)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.8.0.1:11311

process[turtlebot2_maze-1]: started with pid [15644]
[ERROR] [1535564679.315268, 210.837000]: WORLD RESET
[ERROR] [1535564679.324640, 210.846000]: NOT Initialising Simulation Physics Parameters
[WARN] [1535564679.331335, 210.852000]: Start Init ControllersConnection
[WARN] [1535564679.331698, 210.852000]: END Init ControllersConnection
[WARN] [1535564680.745782, 211.494000]: START wait_until_twist_achieved... 
[WARN] [1535564680.778331, 211.550000]: Reached Velocity!
[WARN] [1535564680.778792, 211.550000]: END wait_until_twist_achieved...
[ERROR] [1535564680.797151, 211.566000]: WORLD RESET
[WARN] [1535564681.186834, 211.714000]: new_ranges=5
[WARN] [1535564681.188497, 211.714000]: mod=144
[WARN] [1535564681.189583, 211.714000]: NOT done Validation >>> item=0.749866962433< 0.5
[WARN] [1535564681.190660, 211.714000]: NOT done Validation >>> item=0.922657012939< 0.5
[WARN] [1535564681.191821, 211.714000]: NOT done Validation >>> item=2.44325733185< 0.5
[WARN] [1535564681.192948, 211.714000]: NOT done Validation >>> item=2.64469790459< 0.5
[WARN] [1535564681.194034, 211.714000]: NOT done Validation >>> item=0.914873301983< 0.5
[WARN] [1535564681.195369, 211.714000]: ############### Start Step=>0
[WARN] [1535564681.196458, 211.714000]: Next action is:2
[WARN] [1535564681.215806, 211.714000]: START wait_until_twist_achieved...
[WARN] [1535564681.274124, 211.772000]: Not there yet, keep waiting...
[WARN] [1535564681.330621, 211.828000]: Reached Velocity!
[WARN] [1535564681.331351, 211.828000]: END wait_until_twist_achieved...
...
```

... and so on.

So your robot should start moving and trying actions.

Please confirm that it is working. Otherwise, copy here the whole output of your command.

---

Originally posted by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) with karma: 874 on 2018-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FloppyHank](https://answers.ros.org/users/31941/floppyhank/) on 2018-09-24**:
Yes, you are right. I figured out this a couple of days before but forgot to check this answer back. Thank you.